# Mac OS X - Magic Mouse - increasing the scroll speed

Tags: mac, magic-mouse

I have a Magic Mouse on my iMac and I am using BetterTouchTool. How do I increase the scrolling speed? I want to scroll more swiping smaller distances...

I want to set the scrolling more than the maximum possible at the preference values.

Probably I will need some sort of terminal command.

thanks

Comment: Past the maximum at *System Preferences ‣ Mouse*?

Comment: yes! way more than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply a custom acceleration value: `defaults write -g com.apple.scrollwheel.scaling -float <float>` and relogin.

The scale seems to be roughly linear and to not have any practical maximum limit.

Editing the *NSGlobalDomain* plist in a text editor: `f=~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist; cp $f $f-; plutil -convert xml1 $f; open -a TextEdit $f`

Comment: I can't believe I found this answer after like 3 hours of googling and it actually worked in 2017........... Unreal. How does BetterTouchTool not have this built in?